# How to parse the end of char array?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, char, c-strings

So let's say I have a line that looks like this:

```
"abcdefghi"
```

If I want "hi", and there is nothing that comes after it, how can I parse?

I tried `strtok(str, "'\0'")` but I can't seem to get that to work.

Is there a function in C that will allow me to do this?

Comment: what do you want exactelly? the 2 last char of your string?

Comment: Umm, `strstr(stuff, "hi")` perhaps?

Comment: `printf("%s", "abcdfghi" + 6);`

Comment: @EricPostpischil I want to set another char array to the characters of "hi" so that I can pass to another function. I'm not going to have repeated values or anything else. If I had the line " $t0", then I want to whittle the line down to "t0".

Comment: @Laurence: Is this a correct statement of the problem: `x` is the name of a pointer to char or an array of char with a terminating null character. Copy the last two non-null characters from `x` to an array `y`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, declarations and definitions are needed somewhere earlier in the program:

```
#include <string.h>
…
char y[3]; // Define array to hold results.
```

Then the last two characters of `x` and the terminating null character can be copied with:

```
// Find length of string.
size_t length = strlen(x);

// Copy last two characters.
strcpy(y, x+length-2);
```

Note that this requires that `x` contain at least two characters.

Alternately, the two characters without the terminating null character can be copied with:

```
// Find length of string.
size_t length = strlen(x);

// Copy last two characters without the terminating null character.
strncpy(y, x+length-2, 2);
```

Or:

```
// Find length of string.
size_t length = strlen(x);

// Copy last two characters without the terminating null character.
y[0] = x[length-2];
y[1] = x[length-1];
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, I didn't think C allowed you to copy characters like that. Again, thank you for both clarifying my question and answering it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) to find a substring in your string.

```
char * pointsToHi = strstr( string , "hi") ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that might work. Trying to work it in my code now.